# Calculating the mean of a discrete R.V in a question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have the following HW question:

> There are $N$ balls in a box, $m$ balls with an $S$ for success and
> $N-m$ balls with an $F$ for failure. Choose $n$ balls at random
> ($n\leq N$) and let $X$ = the number of successes.
>
> a. Calculate the probability function $p(\cdot)=P(X=\cdot)$
>
> b.
> Calculate $EX$

I have managed to solve the first part of the question: $$P(X=k)=\frac{\binom{m}{k}\cdot\binom{N-m}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

But I am having difficulty with the second part, I need to evaluate
$$EX=\sum_{k=0}^{\min\{n,m\}}\frac{\binom{m}{k}\cdot\binom{N-m}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}\cdot k$$

I have opened the binomials by definitions and I am stuck there.

How can I calculate $EX$ ? any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By symmetry, the probability of success on each trial is the same as on each other trial.

(Here's a point where people get confused: They say "Doesn't the probability of success on the second trial depend on whether there's a success on the first trial?".  The answer is that the *conditional* probability of success on the second trial, *given* the outcome of the first trial, does depend on the outcome of the first trial.  But *marginal* (or "unconditional") probability of success on the second trial is nonetheless the same as the probability of success on the first trial.)

Let
$$
X_i = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if success occurs on the $i$th trial,} \\ 0 & \text{if not.} \end{cases}
$$
Then $\mathbb E(X) = \mathbb E(X_1+\cdots+X_n) = \mathbb E(X_1)+\cdots+\mathbb E(X_n)$, and all the terms in that last sum are equal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I didn't even think to use linearity and I got really stuck working with the definition.